# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\tan^{-1}n}{n+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

How could I determine the convergence or divergence of this series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\tan^{-1}n}{n+\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

1. For sufficiently big $n$
   $$
   \tan^{-1}n\geq\frac{\pi}{2}-1
   $$
2. For all $n$ 
   $$
   \frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}}\geq\frac{1}{n+n}
   $$
3. The series 
   $$
   \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}
   $$
   diverges